# list elements from table, add the references from other table and use them in ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Tables:

helps (important are id and fecha fields)

[image]

shared helps (helps referenced by other users with a different date)

[image]

So,

All helps from a user (user_id = 1)

```
SELECT * FROM helps WHERE id_user = 1
```

All helps from user and the ones he refferenced

```
SELECT * FROM helps where id_user = 1 or id IN (SELECT helpid FROM shared_helps WHERE userid = 1)
```

I know you guys will find it a very ugly query (I hoped you could show me the light) but it seems to show the results I want. Problem is that this way shared_helps.fecha is ignored so it makes no effect in the ORDER BY, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is `help.id` unique?  And in `shared_helps`, is each combination of `userid, helpid` unique?  Or could the same `userid` be associated with the same `helpid` multiple times?

Comment: Yes to both. help.id is unique and a user can only refer same helpid once @Dems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  helps.*
FROM
  helps
LEFT JOIN
  shared_helps
    ON  shared_helps.helpid = helps.id
    AND shared_helps.userid = 1
WHERE
     helps.id_user = 1
  OR shared_helps.userid = 1
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN helps.id_user = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  shared_helps.fecha
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, try this...

```
ORDER BY
  COALESCE(shared_helps.fecha, helps.fecha)
```

Or possibly this...

```
ORDER BY
  helps.fecha
```

I'm honestly not 100% certain what you need.  Perhaps you could include some sample data and the output you desire for that sampel data?

Comment: I append DESC to your query to get it descending by fecha but its not working... any idea why? i get bot kind of results but the orderby fail.. Why is that case for?

Comment: You're fetching two sets of results.  The first *(set1)* is where the `id_user = 1`, and the second *(set2)* is by searching `shared_helps` first.  My current query orders the results such that *(set1)* always comes first, and that *(set2)* always comes after, ordered by `shared_helps.fecha`.  If you don't want *(set1)* to always come first, remove the `CASE` line from the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Yay! this works! Is there a way to append a row if the result is from shared_helps? like append row shared with a 0 or 1 value?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - I'm not 100% certain what you're asking for now.  I've added two possible `ORDER BY` clauses.  Try them both and play with them until you get what you need.  Or edit your question to include example data and example results so we can see exactly what you are lookign to achieve.

Comment: I didnt explain... I mean, is there a way to add a new row to the result set like is_referenced_item with a 1 value when it is and a 0 value when it isn't?  (So I can know in php)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - You mean a new field/column?  If so, yes.  Just add `CASE WHEN shared_helps.userid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as FoundViaSharedHelps` to your `SELECT` block.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you, try this way:

> SELECT * FROM helps
>   INNER JOIN shared_helps ON helps.user_id =
>   shared_helps.user_id    WHERE helps.user_id = 1
>   ORDER BY shared_helps.fecha ASC|DESC

Comment: You can't assume that all the records have `user_id = 1`. The ones picked out by the OP's sub-query may have a different value in `user_id`.

Comment: its helps.id_user but still the references are not listed

Comment: I see.. the answer below should help you.